# fullPath in Cordova returning as "/"

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am finding that fullPath in Cordova is returning as "/" and 
the FileEntry.toURL() and DirectoryEntry.toURL() are returning paths of the form "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application//Documents” rather than
"cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file”.

This is in upgrading something that works on Cordova 2.7 to 7.0.1 (with cordova file plugin): has anyone any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer is fileSystem.root.toInternalURL().

This returns something of the form "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/” rather than "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application//Documents”